# How to determine refund type while issuing credit memo ? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, creditmemo, refund

i am implementing an functionality where i need to determine refund type while issuing credit memo so based on that i can send different email template to customers.

I have checked in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\CreditmemoSender;`

`send()` but i am not getting refund type in it.

Is their any way we can determine that ?

Thankyou

Comment: what is the refund type and how does it relate to the creditmemo? also where is this data saved?